# HostListener and Angular Universal

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, angular-universal

I'm trying to listen to a `MessageEvent` sent with postMessage in my Angular 2 component.

My first attempt was simply doing:

```
window.addEventListener("message", this.handlePostMessage.bind(this));
```

And then in `ngOnDestroy`:

```
window.removeEventListener("message", this.handlePostMessage.bind(this));
```

However this didn't work as expected. If I navigated to another route and back, there would be two event listeners registered.

So instead I've been trying to decorate the method with [HostListener](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostListener-interface.html), but I can't get this working when using prerendering (Angular Universal with .NET Core using the [`asp-prerender-module`](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/Prerendering/PrerenderTagHelper.cs)).

```
@HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])
private handlePostMessage(msg: MessageEvent) {
    ...
}
```

That gives me the following error on page load:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: MessageEvent is not defined
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Just updated my answer. See Edit #2 to see if it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because MessageEvent is not defined. You must import whatever file defines this.

My @HostListeners look like this:

```
@HostListener("window:savePDF", ["$event"]) savePDF(event) {
    this.savePDFButtonPushed();
}
```

and you can read more about them here:

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

However, I'm currently experiencing the same issue you are -- that if I navigate to another route and back, I now receive two events. And that is using @HostListener. :-(  However I haven't upgraded Angular in a while (currently using 4.4.6), so maybe they've fixed it since that release.

**Edit: Just upgraded to Angular 5.1.0. The 'duplicate events' @HostListener issue remains. :-(

Edit #2: I tried also using window.addEventListener like you tried, and also had the same issue, despite using window.removeEventListener in ngOnDestroy().

This lead me to dig a little deeper, where I found some code I had added to listen to messages from a child iFrame. Any chance you have something similar in your code?

```
        var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
        var eventer = window[eventMethod];
        var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

                // Listen to messages from child window ("unsign" and "savePDF") and pass those along as events to Angular can pick them up in its context
        eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
            window.dispatchEvent( new Event( e.data ) );
        },false);
```

This had been in my page's constructor. I protected it so it only executed the *first* time the page was constructor, and now all is well.